# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger to only run if changes made to data after 9-5 hours

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've created a basic audit table so that if there any any changes to a 'Employee' table be they insert, update, delete, the time, the user and what the action is are stored in a 'audit employee' table.

I just wondered if it was possible so that the trigger would only fire if the changes made on the 'Employee' table were after say 5pm until 7am?

Does anyone have any ideas how this would be possible possibly using SYSDATE?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of an audit trail which doesn't track *every* chnage made to a table?

Comment: @APC - apparently only changes made by Bad People need to be audited.   And, as everyone knows, Bad People only work between the hours of 5 PM and 7 AM.  Only *Good People* work from 7 AM to 5 PM.  You don't need to worry about what Good People do because they're, you know, Good People.  There's no use clogging up the audit trail with audit of actions made by the Good People.  It just wastes disk space.  Worry about the Bad People, and the Good People will take care of themselves.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Maybe they're enforcing a family-friendly work environment. "You WILL stop work at 5pm or suffer a phone call from your friendly HR department"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control whether the trigger will fire based on the time of day.  You can, however, add logic to the trigger so that you only insert data into the history table between certain hours.  Something like

```
IF( to_number( to_char(sysdate, 'hh24')) >= 17 or
    to_number( to_char(sysdate, 'hh24')) < 7 )
THEN
  INSERT INTO employee_history...
END IF;
```

Comment: `IF mod(to_char(sysdate,'hh24')+7, 24) < 14 THEN ...`

Comment: if extract(hour from sysdate) not between 7 and 17