# Oracle Audit Table based on job role

Tags: sql, database, oracle, audit

I've managed to created an audit table in Oracle that audits records when they have been updated, deleted or inserted on the employees table. I have also made it so it only audits records when changes are made out of office hours (9am - 5pm).

IF you want to see the code for this please let me know, but i just wondered would it be possible to only audit records based on job role aswell. In the employee table there is a job role column such as this.

```
 Job_role
 Director
Security Guard II
Administration Manager
Warehouse Assistant I
```

I would only want it to audit changes made by for example a security guard or a warehouse assistant as these jobs roles should not really be interacting with the employee database.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I commented on your first question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15534951/146325 that an audit which only operated in certain hours was pretty worthless. An audit which only monitors cetain tyopes of employees compounds the worthlessness. It is also the wrong approach. If "warehouse assistants" shouldn't be interacting with database tables why have their user accounts got the privileges which allow them to do so? You need to re-think your entire security model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and again i agree with you but i'm currently at university and this is what 'my client' wants on the project im undertaking so i have no choice but to follow what they ask.

Comment: Yeah I hear that a lot.  The problem is not just that you are being asked to build something which is pointless but also that you're not learning anything meaningful about proper software projects.  In real life I would just tell the client to stop being so silly and start work on building something useful instead.

Comment: hah i wish i could i really do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is store the user's job description in a session variable.

To do this you declare a namespace using the CREATE CONTEXT command.  [Docs here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5002.htm#SQLRF01202)

Then you have [an AFTER-LOGON database trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) which queries the USERS table and stores the Job Description in the namespace using `DBMS_SESSION.set_context()`. [Docs here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS054)

Finally, when it comes to the auditing command you read the stored value with `SYS_CONTEXT()`  and make the appropriate decision:

```
if sys_context('AUDIT_INFO', 'JOB_DESCR') = 'Warehouse Assistant I'   
then
    call_your_audit_proc(.....);
end if;
```